How to get a changing file from GitHub
I want to download a file from the release page of a GitHub repository. I do not know how to do this. Currently my code is
#import libraries
import requests
import zipfile
import io

#define the link to the latest GTNH version
GTNHLink = "https://github.com/GTNewHorizons/GT-New-Horizons-Modpack/releases/latest"

#get the path to the old file
OriginalFilePath = "C:\\Users\\********\\CurseforgeUtils\\GTNHAutoUpdate\\GTNHOld.zip"

#download and save the new file
NewFileContent = requests.get(GTNHLink)
NewFile = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(NewFileContent.content))
NewFile.close

but (I assume) because there are multiple files on the page it's not giving me the zip file I want. How do I fix this? The main issue I found with it is that the file name is going to change as new versions are released.

Why are you assuming that the link returns a zip file?

Duplicate of: Is there a link to GitHub for downloading a file in the latest release of a repository?

You can get the list of release files in the assets field, then you can iterate through the list to find the .zip file using asset['name'].endswith('.zip').
response = requests.get(GTNHLink)

if response.status_code == 200:
    release_data = response.json()
    assets = release_data.get('assets', [])

    for asset in assets:
        if asset['name'].endswith('.zip'):
            download_url = asset['browser_download_url']
            file_response = requests.get(download_url)
            with open(OriginalFilePath, "wb") as file:
                file.write(file_response.content)
            break


Tried putting that in but now I am getting a different error that I can not read.
https://pastebin.com/ec00vjbm

Can you share the full traceback of the error as well as the full version of your code? @Penrosian

That link doesn't return JSON.

ha, uh... I was using the wrong link. Oopsie!
